# uninitialized constant UserController, despite building one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

New to web dev and struggling with getting devise to behave.

Whenever a new user registers and hits the submit button, Rails keeps telling me...

```
uninitialized constant UserController
```

I have a user model and user devise migration. 
I've tried making a users_controller.rb as well as user_controller.rb (as Rails appears to want singular for some reason). I'm stumped. Please help!

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  devise_scope :users do
    authenticated :user do
      root "user#show"
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root "devise/sessions#new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: run `rails g controller Users`. this will generate the `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` file.

Comment: Its correct..there is no user_controller.rb ..its USERS_CONTROLLER.RB...its plural

Comment: I already have a `users_controller.rb`. What is causing rails to expect a `user_controller.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

You did not define any routes for `user_controller.rb`.
You can define a singular resource in your routes file like this

```
resource :user
```

Or you can also include`user_controller.rb` actions in `users` resources like this

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'user_controller_action_name'
    post 'user_controller_action_name'
  end
end
```